# What is the best way to deal with default Windows partitions when dual booting 16.04 on fresh Windows 10 install?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I installed windows 10 on a fresh computer with a single drive.  It created 4 partitions (system, c:, hibernation, and recovery).

After freeing up some space on C: and trying to install ubuntu 16.04, the partition space I freed up was "unusable" by ubuntu; looking at other questions on this topic, it seems one cannot have more than 4 partitions on a drive.

My question is, what's the easiest solution? Delete a hibernation partition?

Comment: Is system an older BIOS system that probably had Windows 7 or newer UEFI based hardware. If newer hardware and if you install Windows in UEFI mode, it uses gpt partitioning and that effectively has no partition limit, but 128 by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a maximum of 4 primary partitions, but you can have more extended partitions.  See the following web page for more info

http://www.disk-partition.com/resource/disk-partition-basic-understanding.html

Comment: Actually it is only one extended partition that counts as one of the 4 primary partition, but an unlimited number of logical partitions inside the one extended.